# How to make cladogram?

Tags: php, parsing

Does anyone know how I do a cladogram-parser?

Or maybe a small push/link to some tips.

Wikipedia is using it, but how does I make one in PHP?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Clade

Answer (score 0):

I think that parsing should be fairly easy: I'm going to try using [loco](http://qntm.org/loco) PHP parser generator. But rendering, allocating vertical/horizontal spacing, seems a tough job. As suggested by [DOT page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language) on wikipedia, graphviz could do ([this shape](http://www.graphviz.org/content/psg) for instance seems a good start point).